# Replace value with two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array retrieved from database :

```
Array $result['cities']
(
    [1] => New York, United States
    [2] => London, United Kingdom
)
```

And this associative array :

```
Array $asso
(
    [United States] => us
    [United Kingdom] => gb
)
```

Now, I would like to transform the first array into this:

```
Array $newArray
(
    [1] => us
    [2] => gb
)
```

Of course, it has to be dynamic. I tried by using this but once the if condition is true, I don't know how to select the matched key :

```
if (in_array('New York, United States', $result['cities'])) {
    /// So select the matched value and replace it with "us"...
}

if (in_array('London, United Kingdom', $result['cities'])) {
    /// So select the matched value and replace it with "gb"...
}
```

So, as you understand, my problem can be translated as : **How to replace array A values with values of array B in which A values are B keys?**

Comment: Where is code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this -

```
foreach($result['cities'] as $key => $cityInfo){
  list($city, $country) = explode(',', $cityInfo);
  if(isset($asso[$country])){
    $newArr[$key] = $asso[$country];
  }
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Just, you forgot the first parameter in the explode() : `explode(', ', $cityInfo)`. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$newArray = array_map(function ($e) use ($asso) {
    $countryName = trim(array_pop(explode(',', $e)));
    return $asso[$countryName];
}, $result['cities']);
```

Comment: You should add some context on why the solutions tried in the question did not work and how this answer addresses the problem. It will make this answer more valuable to anyone else who is encountering the same or a similar problem.